# UV Unwrapped Blender texture image is either rotated or stretched, cannot get it to be straight and not stretched

Tags: texturing, uv, image, transform-orientation

I am completely new to Blender. I am making a photo frame in Blender 2.65, and I used a plane to be the 'photo' in the frame, and added a texture to it using a real photo. When I did this directly using materials, it was fine and even rendered (I saw some tutorials say that until you UV unwrap it, the material will not show). After I UV Unwrapped it, some problems occurred. I am using Cycles render.

1. If I select the object and go to edit mode, then press U, and either use the default unwrap or select 'reset', the UV Map is the same size as the image itself. However, the plane I used is not the same proportion as the image (I did this on purpose, printed photos are usually cropped because camera sensors aspect ratio is different to paper aspect ratio). This means that the projected texture is stretched, as in this screenshot.
   [image: stretched texture using UV Unwrap reset/default]
2. If I don't want the stretch, using the above method, I can select "unwrap" (first option). The images have the correct proportion but are rotated, as in this screenshot:
   [image: Texture is rotated]

If I then manually rotate my plane in object mode so the, I have to resize it, because the frame is supposed to be in landscape orientation. After I resize the plane, the projected image/texture is stretched once again.

I've tried all the unwrap options including the project from view bounds, nothing works.

I used the photo of the spheres as it is easier to see the stretched result. The photo is square but my goal is to get the frame to work like in the real world when paper and camera sensors have different aspect ratios: either the photo has to be cropped to fill the frame, or there are borders around the photo if you don't want cropping at all. So ultimately, I'd like to be able to use any image as a texture for the plane, and have the plane render the image in the plane's aspect ratio, not the image's aspect ratio.

You can see the file [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/81shvfa3m1kwk5t/Photo%20frame%202.blend?dl=0).
I'd also appreciate it if someone can add 'stretched' and 'rotated' textures as a tag for me.

Comment: Try using the **Project from view (Bounds)** Unwrap option, when viewing the image perpendicular

Comment: Hi, I've tried all the unwrap options including the project from view bounds, nothing works. I'll add that to my main question.

Comment: To make a square image fill a rectangular frame you either need to stretch it or crop it. Enable the import image as planes addon which will create a mesh plane that is sized to match an image.

Comment: Hi Sambler, I am aware that a square photo needs to be cropped, this is not my question, and I have already clarified that in my question. I simply want the model to act like a frame in the real world would, please see the second last paragraph of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You still don't have a plane there (from the problem of your last question). At the top you can see, there are 8 vertices and 5 faces.

delete the vertices that are only connected to the side walls of your cube. then normal unwrapping works just fine.

[image]

Comment: I think you downloaded the old file, I didn't update the link after I changed the file. I have updated it now, the plane should have only 1 face.

Comment: I downloaded the right file (checked and downloaded again, it's the same file). you had a cube instead of a plane and only deleted one face. 6 - 1 = 5. and that's what you see in the top menu bar. 8 Verts, 12 edges and 5 faces. delete the side faces or just unwrap the main face you want to texture.